# `munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer` and SIGABRT in Fortran Fourier transform

Tags: fortran, fft, sigabrt

For a project in my mater's degree I have to make a program to calculate the Fourier transform of a signal.
I open the data of a .dat file and then I have to use a **subroutine** to **calculate the Fourier transform of my signal and return it in an array**. I calculate the real part and the imaginary part of the Fourier transform.

- "npts" is the number of points in my sine wave.
- "nbft" is the number of frequency of my Fourier transform.
- "temps" mean "time" in French.**
- "F_reel" if the real part of the Fourier transform.
- "F_im" is the imaginary part.
- "delta_nu" is the temporal resolution.
- "freq" is the frequency.
- "signal" is the sine wave value.

I tried to translate the program so you can understand what I try to do.

**Everything seems to be fine but I keep getting the error SIGABRT.

I think the problem is in my subroutine, at the step 2 but I am not able to find how to solve the problem.**

Here is my code :

```
program puissance_sinus1_nom
                    !!!!! MAIN PROGRAM !!!!!

! DECLARATION OF CONSTANTS AND VARIABLES 
implicit none
integer :: i, ios=0, npts, nbft
double precision, dimension(:), allocatable :: freq, puis
double precision, dimension(:), allocatable :: temps, signal

! INSTRUCTIONS
! 1. Open the file
open(25, file='sinus1_nom.dat', status='old', &
         action='read', iostat=ios)

! 2. Lines count
read(25,*)npts        ! The number of points (npts) is indicated
                      ! in the 1st line of the file I open
allocate(temps(npts))
allocate(signal(npts))
write(*,*)" "

do i = 1,npts
   read(25,*)temps(i),signal(i)
enddo


if (mod(npts,2) .eq. 0) then
   nbft = npts/2 +1
else
   nbft = (npts +1)/2
endif

write(*,*)"Number of frequencies :",nbft
write(*,*) " "
write(*,*) " "

! 3. Use of subroutine
allocate(freq(nbft))
allocate(puis(nbft))
call calcul_fourier(npts,signal,temps,nbft,freq,puis)


! Close everything
deallocate(freq)
deallocate(puis)
deallocate(temps)
deallocate(signal)

close(25)
end program puissance_sinus1_nom

                    !!!!! SUBROUTINE !!!!!

subroutine calcul_fourier(npts,signal,temps,nbft,freq,puis)
! DECLARATION OF VARIABLES
implicit none 
integer :: i, k
double precision :: delta_nu, pi=4*atan(1.)
double precision, dimension(nbft) :: F_reel, F_im

integer, intent(in) :: npts, nbft
double precision, dimension(npts), intent(in) :: temps, signal
double precision, dimension(nbft), intent(out) :: freq, puis

! INSTRUCTIONS
! 1. Frequency resolution calculation
delta_nu = (1./temps(npts))*1.d6
write(*,*)"delta_nu = ",delta_nu," micro Hz"

! 2. Calculation of real and imaginary parts of Fourier transform
do k=1, nbft
   freq(k) = (k-1)*delta_nu
enddo

do k=0, nbft+1
   F_reel(k) = 0
   F_im(k) = 0
   do i=1, npts
   F_reel(k) = F_reel(k) + (2./npts)*signal(i)*cos(2*pi*freq(k)*temps(i))
   F_im(k) = F_im(k) + (2./npts)*signal(i)*sin(2*pi*freq(k)*temps(i))
   enddo
   write(*,*)F_reel(k)    ! display to see if it works
enddo

write(*,*) " "
write(*,*) " "
write(*,*) " "

! 3. power calculation (magnitude^2)
do k=1,nbft
   puis(k) = F_reel(k)**2 + F_im(k)**2
enddo

end subroutine calcul_fourier
```

I use `write(*,*)F_reel(k)` to display the value of the real part of the Fourier transform to check if the program behave correctly, and I am expecting it to return me all the value it calculates.

However, I keep getting this message:

```
*** Error in `./puissance_sinus1_nom.x': munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer: 0x0000000000e07d10 ***

Program received signal SIGABRT: Process abort signal.

Backtrace for this error:
#0  0x7F4E9392D407
#1  0x7F4E9392DA1E
#2  0x7F4E92E4A0DF
#3  0x7F4E92E4A067
#4  0x7F4E92E4B447
#5  0x7F4E92E881B3
#6  0x7F4E92E8D98D
#7  0x4013A6 in calcul_fourier_
#8  0x401C0A in MAIN__ at puissance_sinus1_nom.f90:?
Abandon
```

Obviously I am doing something wrong, but I can't see what it is.
Do you have any idea?

Comment: Welcome. Be sure to take the [Tour] and read [ask]. It is always important to compile your program for debugging. First, to get a meaningful backtrace, you should use the `-g` flag. Then, to get error checking and other warnings, use flags such as `-Wall -fcheck=all` for gfortran or `-warn -check` for Intel. Consult your compiler's manual.

Comment: You subroutine `subroutine calcul_fourier` is external. It is not in a module (preferred!) nor it is internal to the program (learn contains). It is very easy to make errors this way. All subroutines should be placed into a module to avoid errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your loop

```
do k=0, nbft+1
   F_reel(k) = 0
   F_im(k) = 0
   do i=1, npts
   F_reel(k) = F_reel(k) + (2./npts)*signal(i)*cos(2*pi*freq(k)*temps(i))
   F_im(k) = F_im(k) + (2./npts)*signal(i)*sin(2*pi*freq(k)*temps(i))
   enddo
   write(*,*)F_reel(k)    ! display to see if it works
enddo
```

accesses indexes `0` and `nbft+1`, but you arrays are declared from `1` to `nbft`:

```
double precision, dimension(nbft) :: F_reel, F_im
```

That is an error, you cannot access arrays out of bounds.

This error can be found by your compiler. Just enable error checking, use flags such as `-Wall -fcheck=all` for gfortran or `-warn -check` for Intel. Consult your compiler's manual.

BTW, computing the Fourier transform from the definition is very inefficient, you should use the **Fast** Fourier Transform (FFT). There are many libraries you can use.

Comment: Thank you Vladimir, you resolved my problem ! I didn't know how to debug my program, the teacher didn't told me I was able to and how to.  
Thanks for the explanations on how to debug, kind of you ! Actually I had to create a Fourier transform by myself, as a part of the project. But next time I'll definitely use the FFT.

Comment: Thanks. Consider using a FFT library, it is much faster.